# Margins are not correct with \geometry{ ... } and \documentclass{Thesis}

Tags: margins, geometry, thesis, documentclass

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11.5pt, oneside]{Thesis} %ECS Thesis style by Steve Gunn

%Set margins
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    a4paper,
    top=20mm,
    left=20mm,
    bottom=20mm,
    right=20mm
}
```

Here is the code I am using to setup my document and the margins are definitely all wrong. The text goes off the page on the top and left. I am trying to make all margins 20mm in length. It seems when I change top=40mm and left=40mm(or so) the text makes it into the page, but I can not be certain if the margin is actually 20mm.

I've tried changing the documentclass and I think the \geometry{...} command works but I want to use the Thesis documentclass.

Comment: `Thesis` is not a standard document class in TeX.  You'll need to talk to Steve Gunn, or figure out what it is about `Thesis` that you want.

Comment: Wecome to TeX.SE. Please read about [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that)s. If you say `geometry` worked with another class, than you should open the class file (`.cls`) and debug it. The class Thesis *probably* sets something take interferes with packages you insert yourself. It may be (1) something wrong made or (2) made in order to not allow user's editions. Without the class, you can only *guess* what is going on.

Comment: Oh. I see. Thank you! I didn't know about the {Thesis} part using the Thesis.cls.